# Sequelize, custom setter, doesn't set

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Unfortunatly the documentation for model property setters and getters is somewhat deficient and I'm having trouble getting my little setter to work.

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function( sequelize, DataTypes )
{
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
        username:       { type:DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false },
        email:          { type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
        userlevel:      { type:DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull:false, defaultValue:0 },
        password:       { type:DataTypes.STRING, 
            set: function(v) {
                var pw = this;
                var r;
                bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt) {
                    bcrypt.hash(v, salt, function(err,hash) {
                        pw.setDataValue('password', hash);
                    });
                });
            } }
    });



    return User;
}
```

Now from what I can tell based on github issues custom setters on properties are not called on create() so calling

```
db.User.create( { username:'guest', email:'guest@guest', userlevel:1, password:'guest' } ).success( function(record) { console.log(record) });
```

results in the following insert:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`username`,`email`,`userlevel`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'guest','guest@guest',100,'2014-02-25 01:05:17','2014-02-25 01:05:17');
```

so I went ahead and added the following in the success clause:

```
u.set('password', 'stupid');
u.save();
```

I can see that my setter is getting properly called and that the hash is getting set on the password property. However once the setter ends and I return back to my u.save() line the u object is back to it's previous state with no password set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are experiencing this issue, because getters and setters are currently only support synchronous actions. Saying this, you can find a working solution here:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username:       { type: DataTypes.STRING,  allowNull: false, unique: true   },
    email:          { type: DataTypes.STRING,  allowNull: false, unique: true   },
    userlevel:      { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull:false,  defaultValue:0 },
    password:       {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        set:  function(v) {
            var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
            var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(v, salt);

            this.setDataValue('password', hash);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hooks/life cycle events for Sequelize are async, together with .changed() once could implement hashing in a hook if the password field has changed.

Comment: Does it say somehwere in the docs that getters and setters are sync only? I would love to be able to blame myself for just speed reading past it instead of wasting a good hour poking and prodding at this issue.

Comment: Actually the docs are super ugly at the moment when it comes to getters/setters. We will work on that.

Comment: Please not if you use this, validations will fail to work

Comment: The setter is not invoked when you use the findOrCreate method. The password is stored as-is and not as its hash. Why is that? Checked back. If raw is true for above method, it will not invoke the setters.